# Black background in Gnome control center

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, gnome-control-center

I must have messed up something, because all of the subwindows in Gnome control center have black backgrounds. It makes them quite hard to read. I use Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell 3.8. Changing themes does not help. What CSS property controls the background of these windows? What has gone wrong here?
BTW the main Gnome control center window is fine (i.e. has a white background).
Thanks,
Jos.

Comment: Update: the black background only appears when I call the control center from the user menu. If I enter "gnome-control-center" on a command line, or e.g. "gnome-control-center info", the backgrounds are fine. So perhaps it is a bug after all?

Comment: Update: OK never mind. It is a bug. It goes away when I disable the overlay scrollbars, and comes back again when I reenable them. So no overlay scrollbars for me then.